# Nest-api camera issues

Tags: nest-api

I have created product in developer console and have attached camera to my profile, but when I am trying to get camera info through api by the request:

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/cameras?auth=auth_token
```

Its just empty object. How can I get camera info? Might be I should to attach camera to product somehow?

Comment: Not an answer, sorry, but I've got exactly the same problem. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the Nest Home Simulator or the Nest API itself. Sending a HTTP GET request to https://developer-api.nest.com/devices gives me all the info except for the Nest Cams.

Comment: No, there is the same result, just empty object "{}"

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by this?

Comment: do you have camera permissions? is it a real camera? is it online?

Comment: Yes, camera is online. Read/write camera permission is also added.